# Tool to search for string exact matches in lots of files on hard-drive (10s of gigas). Is there something out there?

Tags: text-search, file-search

I'm looking for a tool that will allow me to run exact queries (and with this I mean searching for something like `def main(s: Array[String]): Unit = {`, containing any kind of symbols, over a set of directories in my hard-drive that can span tens of Gigabytes worth of files). The files will be periodically updated, so there should be a way to update the indexes efficiently. Optionally it would also be able to search for regex expressions, but that would also only be a nice to have. The returning results for a query should file the filename and the surrounding text.

The search should give the results back fairly quick (sub-second, ideally).

I'm aware of tools such as Elastic Search, but they seem to be targeting word search, not really "exact search". Or am I wrong?

I already did a prototype of something similar just for fun, but I'm right now deciding if I should proceed forward with this to solve my real world business issue, or just use a battle-tested, open-source solution instead.

Comment: how about the software choices? gratis, proprietary or any other things?

Comment: other things like which operating system should it run on?

Answer (score 1):

Free, multi-platform, fast, source code, ... (Some of these index inside compressed files, perform OCR, thesaurus search for similar words, SQL  database indexing, provide *instant* results instead of waiting a second, etc.)

In order from simple to complicated and powerful:

- [DocFetcher](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html)
- [Open Semantic Search](https://www.opensemanticsearch.org/)
- [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/about/sphinx/)
- [CSIRO Arch](https://www.atnf.csiro.au/computing/software/arch/)
- [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/)
- [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)